# When viewing user's full site list in iOS app, moderator diamonds are not shown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, moderators

I was viewing a site moderator's full list of accounts in the iOS app and noticed that it did not have a diamond marker next to the site they moderate, which it does in the web view.

Could we please add this? Occasionally when I'm in the app I see someone I recognize as a moderator from another site but can't remember which... but the app won't show me without clicking on each individual site to see their account there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be added in 1.6.6.1.

The funny thing is the code was already in there to do this, we just never requested that field from the server so it was coming back as null.

Comment: YAY! Awesome. Glad to hear it.